# NetLogo nested list items to character seperated string

Tags: netlogo

I have a triple nested list:

```
[ 
  [ 
    [a b] 
    [c d] 
    ... 
  ] 
  [
    [e f]
    [g h]
    ... 
  ] 
]
```

I want a string with the format `a,c,...` respectively `e,g,..`

My current approach is to first make a new list with as much items as the first nested list has and add the first items of the lists within said list. 
Afterwards then new list is reduced:

```
let nl ( n-values ( length ( item 0 list) ) [ i -> ( item 0 ( item i ( item 0 list)) ) ] )
reduce [ [a b] -> (word a "," b) ] nl
```

Is there a better way to do this, as in this approach it is very difficult to maintain the overview of the "denesting" of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list looks like:

```
let a ( list ( list [ "a" "b" ] [ "c" "d" ] ) ( list [ "e" "f" ] [ "g" "h" ] ) )
```

I'm not sure that this makes it easier to keep track of the denesting, but you could nest a `map` within another to get the order you want:

```
  print map [ x -> map [ y -> item 0 y ] x ] a
```

If you want it as a list of strings with commas, I like the `csv:to-row` primitive from the `csv` extension:

```
print map [ x -> csv:to-row map [ y -> item 0 y  ] x ] a
```

Again, not sure that it's more straightforward but it's an alternative approach!

**Edit:**

As Seth pointed out, `map [ y -> item 0 y ]` can be replaced with `map first`- so the modified versions would look like:

```
  print map [ x -> map first x ] a
```

and

```
  print map [ x -> csv:to-row map first x ] a
```

Thanks Seth!

Comment: isn't `map [ y -> item 0 y ]` just `map first`?

Comment: @SethTisue ... yes.  Thanks for the catch, modified.